# Are any deities associated with Incarnum?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, religions-and-deities, meldshaping

Are any deities or similar powerful entities associated with **incarnum**, the magical substance from [*Magic of Incarnum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_of_Incarnum) that allows meldshapers to shape and bind soulmelds?

Comment: Incarnum as in the material introduced by *Magic of Incarnum*? So, deities associated with the material? Or something else like the broad scope of Incarnum-related magic?

Comment: Anything, because I'm not finding alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, there are no Incarnum associated Powers, Demi-Powers or other outer planar beings of worship.

Magic of Incarnum, p96 states, in part:

> INCARNUM DOMAIN
>   Deities: None. Clerics of any deity can select this domain, as
>   well as clerics who venerate a pantheon or no deity at all.

Therefore, there are no Powers (some call them deities) that have incarnum as part of their portfolio. However, apparently, anyone can select it, no matter whom they do or don't worship.

---

On an unrelated note, this DM uses in their own campaigns incarnum as the default form of magic of the outer planes, it is the "native" form of magic. While it has been learned on other planes, it seemed that a form of "soul magic" would be most appropriate to have an outer planar origin.

On another unrelated note, this lack could also serve as the opportunity for a DM and/or player consulting with their DM to exercise their creative chops, and assign or create some, which could be a fun bit of world-building.

Comment: Technically there is the Eternal Host, a conglomeration of eternal warrior souls that grants access to the blademeld soulmeld, but I think that's it.

Comment: @Cellheim Are they worshiped, by chance? Or is it more of a feat/class feature type option?

Comment: It sounds like they just draw power from it and that it might not be sentient exactly.

Comment: I thought the *No gods of incarnum* thing stemmed from the Pact Primeval or whatever its called that says *nobody* — and that includes you, deities — can get down with the nitty-gritty of preincarnate souls? I kind of thought that was what the whole adventure *Bastion of Broken Souls* was about. Or is my headcanon accidentally equating two different things when it has incarnum = preincarnate soul power?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I believe you are very much on the right track, though I am unsure if this is a lucky coincidence, rather than the authors of *Magic of Incarnum* having *Bastion of Broken Souls* in mind when deciding not to include any deities especially interested in incarnum. Still, even if it is a coincidence, the coincidence is so striking that it would be worthwhile to write up as an answer, I think.

Comment: I agree that it is more likely to be a coincidence than planned, however, the adventure in question then promptly proceeded to break the premise in that the whole point is that someone IS attempting to mess with preincarnate souls, if I recall correctly.  Also, the Pact Primeval didn't deal with pre-incarnate souls, only what happened to souls after death, from what my memories and research reveals.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Incarnum is defined as: *Incarnum is an amorphous magical substance made up of the soul energies of all sentient creatures—living, dead, and, it is theorized, those even not yet born.* in the MoI book, p.4. Also, the power of it is simply "borrowed", not consumed or used up when using soulmelds and suchlike. So, maybe that technically doesn't count as messing with preincarnates.